# perform segue to bring user to chat with post creator

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, segue

I try to create a button which should bring the normal user to the chatController with the creator of a post

Comment: Add code of ChatController

Comment: It looks like the problem is that `showChatControllerForUser` expects a value of type `User`and you are sending a string. I am not sure what we can help with.

Comment: I've edited my question and provided the code for showChatControllerForUser, I hope you can help me @JoakimDanielson

Comment: addedByUser should be of type User. Since showChatControllerForUserCreator function is expecting a user type.

Comment: Like I said, I am not sure what we can help you with? The issue is obvious, you are sending the value of `addedByUser` which is of type `String` to a method that expects a value of type `User`. Maybe you need to change you `Job` class...

Comment: The direct fix in the code you show is `func showChatControllerForUserCreator(_ user: String) {`. But it depends on what you then do with `user` in the rest of that code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues here, and really too many to address in a single answer but let me try to point you in the right direction.

Lets start with this

```
let user = job?.addedByUser
self.messagesController?.showChatControllerForUser(user)
```

so the user var is assigned from the Job Class

```
class Job {
    var addedByUser: String!
```

Notice that addedByUser property is a string, therefor the userVar is a string.

However, you're passing it to a function which requires a user class, not a string.

```
func showChatControllerForUserCreator(_ user: User) {
```

Which then throws an error

> Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type
>   'User'

The way to fix it is to decide if a user is a String or something else. It would most likely be a UserClass that you create

```
class UserClass {
   var uid = ""
   var user_name = ""
}
```

at the same time you need to have your users stored in a users node

```
users
  uid_0
    user_name = "Henry"
  uid_1
    user_name = "Bud"
```

and in your Jobs class, store a reference to the user with it's uid.

This could get rather lengthy but the next step is, after you loaded your job, to then load the user from it's uid. The JobClass would be

```
class Job {
    var addedByUid: String! //this will be the users Firebase uid
    etc etc
```